# Linker errors when compiling OpenMP `target` directive using Clang 6 (trunk) with nvptx target

Tags: cuda, openmp, llvm-clang

I want to run OpenMP4+ code on my Nvidia GPU using LLVM/Clang. I downloaded and compiled llvm/clang/omp libraries from trunk following the instructions found here: https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html and here: https://openmp.llvm.org/. I did not build Compiler-RT and libcxx, but I don't think that would make any difference.

My CMake command was this: `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DOPENMP_ENABLE_LIBOMPTARGET=ON`

I wrote a very basic program with a single OpenMP `target` directive:

```
int main(void)
{
    #pragma omp target
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I compile it with this:
`/home/user/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -v main.cpp -fopenmp -lomptarget -fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda --cuda-path=/home/user/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0`

In case you ask: Yes, I haven't set up my paths for the compiler but I made sure that my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points where the `libomptarget` is located.

And here is the output/error I get after executing the above command (The last ~10 lines show the error):

```
<If this is too much information, just go to the last 10 lines to see the error>
clang version 6.0.0 (trunk 312875)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/user/opt/llvm/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/6.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/7.2.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
Found CUDA installation: /home/user/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0, version 7.0
 "/home/user/opt/llvm/bin/clang-6.0" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-llvm-bc -emit-llvm-uselists -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -resource-dir /home/user/opt/llvm/lib/clang/6.0.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /home/user/opt/llvm/lib/clang/6.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /home/user/opt/llvm/lib/clang/6.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /tmp -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 190 -fopenmp -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /tmp/main-be2d35.bc -x c++ main.cpp -fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda
clang -cc1 version 6.0.0 based upon LLVM 6.0.0svn default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/user/opt/llvm/lib/clang/6.0.0/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /home/user/opt/llvm/lib/clang/6.0.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/home/user/opt/llvm/bin/clang-6.0" -cc1 -triple nvptx64-nvidia-cuda -aux-triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -S -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -no-integrated-as -fuse-init-array -mlink-cuda-bitcode /home/user/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/nvvm/libdevice/libdevice.compute_20.10.bc -target-feature +ptx42 -target-cpu sm_20 -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -resource-dir /home/user/opt/llvm/lib/clang/6.0.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0 -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /home/user/opt/llvm/lib/clang/6.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /home/user/opt/llvm/lib/clang/6.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fno-dwarf-directory-asm -fdebug-compilation-dir /tmp -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 190 -fopenmp -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /tmp/main-7ffbd7.s -x c++ main.cpp -fopenmp-is-device -fopenmp-host-ir-file-path /tmp/main-be2d35.bc
clang -cc1 version 6.0.0 based upon LLVM 6.0.0svn default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/user/opt/llvm/lib/clang/6.0.0/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /home/user/opt/llvm/lib/clang/6.0.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
"/home/user/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/bin/ptxas" -m64 -O0 -v --gpu-name sm_20 --output-file /tmp/main-64fc86.cubin /tmp/main-ca9e59.s -c
ptxas info    : 1 bytes gmem, 8 bytes cmem[14]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '__omp_offloading_803_18004c0_main_l3' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for __omp_offloading_803_18004c0_main_l3
0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 5 registers, 32 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Function properties for __omp_offloading_803_18004c0_main_l3_worker
24 bytes stack frame, 8 bytes spill stores, 8 bytes spill loads
"/home/user/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2017/cuda/8.0/bin/nvlink" -o /tmp/main-f247e3.out -v -arch sm_20 -L/home/user/opt/llvm/lib -lomptarget-nvptx main-64fc86.cubin
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '__kmpc_kernel_init' in 'main-64fc86.cubin'
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '__kmpc_kernel_deinit' in 'main-64fc86.cubin'
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '__kmpc_kernel_parallel' in 'main-64fc86.cubin'
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '__kmpc_kernel_end_parallel' in 'main-64fc86.cubin'
nvlink info    : 1 bytes gmem, 8 bytes cmem[14]
nvlink info    : Function properties for '__omp_offloading_803_18004c0_main_l3':
nvlink info    : used 18 registers, 24 stack, 0 bytes smem, 32 bytes cmem[0], 0 bytes lmem
clang-6.0: error: fatbinary command failed with exit code 255 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea which library is supposed to have these `__kmpc*` symbols?
 I tried to run:

`nm libomptarget.so | grep __kmpc_kernel_parallel`

and

`nm libomptarget.rtl.cuda.so | grep __kmpc_kernel_parallel`,

but both commands return nothing.

Finally, if I remove `-fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda` from my compile flags, I get no linker errors. But of course in that case no CUDA code is generated.

Any feedback that may help me to figure out what is going on, where these symbols are supposed to be located, and why they are not there, is more than welcome.

Comment: https://parallel-computing.pro/index.php/forum/general-en/17-blog-post-openmp-4-0-on-nvidia-cuda-gpus

Comment: @talonmies thanks for this. However, it confuses me more. Indeed the old repository of libomptarget would generate a library called libomptarget-nvptx. And indeed, in my case, nvlinker adds -lomptarget-nvptx. However, libomptarget is now part of llvm and there is no need to download libomptarget from the github repo quoted in the link you sent me (right?). Strangely, this new libomptarget version does not generate a libomptarget-nvptx library (I even grepped all CMakeLists.txt files). Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Read the very end -- I am going to guess that the sm_20 build target is the problem.

Comment: I am afraid I am still confused. At the very end the user talks about missing sm_20 code in lib omptarget-nvptx. Yet, I do not have this file, nor the libomptarget (the new one located at the llvm repository) is supposed to create it. Strangely though, in my case, the nvlinker tries to link it. Also, the new version of libomptarget does not appear to understand the cmake flag "-DOMPTARGET_NVPTX_SM=30,35". Finally, I am not quite sure how I can instruct llvm/clang in my compilation command to try and generate sm_30 code. --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_30 does not work. (it still tries to generate sm_20)

Comment: I got around to trying it myself and couldn't get it to work either. At this stage I think we can only conclude that it is still broken and not fit for use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately OMP target offloading support for the nvptx device hasn't been upstreamed as yet. A recent branch is available on github with build instructions at the wiki
https://github.com/clang-ykt/clang/wiki

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I tried to compile the code from the GitHub repo you provided (while following the instructions from the GitHub page) but I get the error `clang-4.0: error: cannot find CUDA installation.  Provide its path via --cuda-path... blah blah`. Are there any CMake flags I can use to define the cuda path? I have it installed, but it is not in a standard location. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get this error when compiling an OpenMP program or when building the compiler?  Could you attach the entire log to get more context regarding the error?